# How to make grafana ingress application to work on subdomain path

Tags: kubernetes-helm, grafana, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I am using this helm chart to deploy grafana ingress - https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/grafana/grafana/6.24.1

I need to establish path-based routing to make it work on mycustomdomain.com/grafana

I update the helm release to change the default root url  path

helm upgrade my-grafana grafana/grafana --set grafana.ini.server.root_url=http://mycustomdomain.com/grafana

My ingress file

```
annotations:
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: mycustomdomain.com
      http:
          - path: /grafana
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: grafana
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

My url is not routing correctly.
It was working fine when i use default / location